# .NET MVC routes and Server.Transfer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a route in a controller handling:

```
/my-site-{x}
```

However, it is taking over from a set of legacy resources living at urls like:

```
/my-site-some_value.htm
```

So I figured I'd write an `HttpModule` that would do a `Server.Transfer` from the old urls (ending in `.htm`) to the new ones (using extensionless urls introduced for MVC and IIS7). Actually, the reason I'm using an `HttpModule` is because the old resources were routed by an `HttpModule`, before routing was an actual part of .NET, so I did not want to duplicate the transfer code in all of the separate .aspx's that were actually handling the requests.

To my surprise, my code encountered errors as they began to be unable to recognize the value of the `{x}` url parameter. Upon inspecting it, I realized that instead of

```
"some_value"
```

I was seeing

```
"some_value.htm"
```

AFTER the `Server.Transfer`.

TL;DR; The route dictionary receives url's but uses the `RawUrl` property which gets the original path before any rewriting, as opposed to what `Server.Transfer` promises, which is "restarts the .net processing pipeline, with the current request just with a new url path". Is there an elegant way around this, other than adding code in my MVC controller that then strips out the `.htm` again?

Comment: MVC supports routes with extensions, so i am why would you use an HttpModule with Server.Transfer, when you can just configure separate routes with .htm extensions in ASP.NET MVC Routing?

Comment: It is because the `.htm` extension is already mapped to another handler. The project I am working on is migrating from webforms to MVC, and we can't unattach all `.htm` extensions from the page handler yet.